# How to connect to MySQL using RIDE

Tags: mysql, robotframework

Using RIDE, I want to connect to MySQL Database.

I have downloaded the [DatabaseLibrary](https://franz-see.github.io/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html) and MySQL. I need to execute queries from MySQL for validating.

How to connect to MySQL using RIDE?

Comment: Does the [official documentation](http://franz-see.github.com/Robotframework-Database-Library/api/0.5/DatabaseLibrary.html) help? Example usage and all needed commands on one page!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simplified RF test setup using MySQL database on localhost:

```
*** Settings ***
library             DatabaseLibrary
library             pymysql
Suite Setup         Connect To Database    @{database}

*** Variables ***
@{database}     pymysql     dbname    user    password    localhost  3306
```

Comment: It gives me `NoSectionError: No section: 'default'` Exception!