# Why I am getting error by connecting to db using pymssql in Robot Framework IDE (RIDE)?

Tags: python, automation, robotframework

Giving the below steps:

1. Installed "DatabaseLibrary" using (pip install
   robotframework-databaselibrary).
2. Installed pymssql (pymssql-2.1.1.win32-py2.7.exe (md5)) through this
   link https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pymssql/2.1.1#downloads.
3. I opened RIDE & Imported both libraries (Selenium2Library & DatabaseLibrary)
4. I did write this script:
   Connect To Database    pymssql    utc-trsry-db2    sa    sa

   Error message: (20009, 'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist\nNet-Lib error during Unknown error (10035)\n')

so anyone can help me & tell me why it is not working ?!

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to have server address and port defined. Have you tried defining connection like described in this earlier case [11323209](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11323209/how-to-connect-to-mysql-using-ride)?